# write test before implementation python

Tags: python

I have a quick question. I'm supposed to write a simple test for a function before it was implemented. The test code is the following:

```
def test(expected_discount: float = 0.3) -> tuple[bool, str]:

    item = Item("Item 1", 1, 1.0, expected_discount)
    total_price = item.calculate_item_total_price() 
    actual_discount = round(1.0 - (total_price / (item.unit_price * item.quantity)), 2)
    fail_case = actual_discount != expected_discount
   

    if fail_case:
        return (False, f"Error in test_calculate_item_price_converts_discount: Incorrect discount\n  - Expected: {expected_discount}\n  - Actual: {actual_discount}")
    else:
        return (True, "Item.calculate_item_price correctly converts discount_percent to discount")
```

The "calculate_item_total_price" has not been implemented yet and doesn't return anything. Once I implement it, it works perfectly. But if i'm trying to use the same code without implementing it, I get a "noneType" error. How can i make this test work without implementing the calculate_item_price function? Thanks.

Comment: The entire _point_ of writing a test before implementing it is to have the test fail, and then see that it succeeds when the implementation is done…!? A proper test framework would simply mark the test as failed, regardless of whether it fails because it has an internal error or because it "returns False".

Comment: You could use `if hasattr(item, "calculate_item_total_price"):` and change the test based on the result.

Comment: Also you can use try-except

Comment: BTW, trying to compare floats to floats like this, you probably gonna have a bad time as well…

Answer (score 3):

When you write the test before the function this is typically the starting point:

```
def my_func(x):
    """Implement logic..."""
    pass
```

Then you write a test, say that you want to verify that given a certain input the expected output is returned. You do so by using the `assert` keyword in Python, which raises an exception if it is passed a statement that is falsy. When that happens, it means that the test failed.

```
def test_my_func():
    expected = 42
    result = my_func("What is the meaning of life?")
    assert result == expected
```

To run the test above I recommend to use a test framework. `pytest` is probably the best choice but there are other alternatives. Here's an extreme simplification of what a test framework does.

```
def run_test(test_func):
    try:
        test_func()
    except AssertionError:
        print("Test failed")
    else:
        print("Test passed")
```

You can now run the test that you created and see that it fails.

```
>>> run_test(test_my_func)
Test failed
```

Now you can start implementing the logic of `my_func` until you receive a "Test passed".

Answer (score 0):

Try to check that calculate_item_total_price returns something which is not None:

```
def test(expected_discount: float = 0.3) -> tuple[bool, str]:

    item = Item("Item 1", 1, 1.0, expected_discount)
    total_price = item.calculate_item_total_price()
    assert total_price is not None
    actual_discount = round(1.0 - (total_price / (item.unit_price * item.quantity)), 2)
    fail_case = actual_discount != expected_discount
   

    if fail_case:
        return (False, f"Error in test_calculate_item_price_converts_discount: Incorrect discount\n  - Expected: {expected_discount}\n  - Actual: {actual_discount}")
    else:
        return (True, "Item.calculate_item_price correctly converts discount_percent to discount")
```

Comment: That will raise another kind of exception, which OP's "test framework" (in as far as there is one) will probably also complain about.